# Change subject line of forwarded email

Tags: email, krl

The [Kynetx Docs](http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Email_Endpoint) describe the parameters that can be passed to the `email:forward()` and `email:reply()` actions. The subject line of the email is not one of them.

I'm trying to build an email routing application of sorts that would require me to be able to change the subject line of emails. I specifically don't want it to say "Forward:" or any variants of that.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you can't. What you can do is start from our email endpoint source and add the option yourself.

Or, you can submit a request, and we can add the feature. :)

Comment: If I were to add the option myself, how would I tie that back into the ruleset? Would I push the new code back to you?